# Equivalence of categories between finite étale covers of connected scheme and finite continuous permutation representations of étale fundamental group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, etale-covers

The title and tags say it all: I am looking for a clean statement and proof of the equivalence of categories between finite étale covers of a connected $k$-scheme and finite continuous permutation representations of the étale fundamental group $\pi_1(X, \overline{x})$ given by the fiber functor.

I need this result for my thesis, but I do not have the space necessary to prove it, so I would like a clear reference I can cite. This is stated in passing at the start of Section 6 in Szamuely's *Galois Group and Fundamental Groups*, but the proof consists of various remarks spread out throughout the entirety of the preceding section, and even then there's some work to be done. If possible, I would love a a wholly contained proof so that I can reference this away. I only need the result for reductive group schemes over the algebraic closure of a finite field, so total generality is not necessary.

Comment: This is the content of SGA 1, exp. V. In particular Theorem 4.1, and §7 which explains that the theorem applies to connected schemes.

Comment: @abx What exactly is SGA 1, exp. V? Apologies, I'm a novice in the field.

Comment: @mskilleter SGA is "Séminaire de Géometrie Algébrique"

Comment: [SGA 1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0206203.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like the notes from the 2016-2017 edition of the Stanford number theory learning seminar. The result that you want is Theorem 3.4 [here](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/%7Econrad/Weil2seminar/Notes/L3.pdf).